# For loop pandas and numpy: Performance

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops, numpy

I have coded the following for loop. The main idea is that in each occurrence of 'D' in the column 'A_D', it looks for all the possible cases where some specific conditions should happen. When all the conditions are verified, a value is added to a list.

```
a = []
for i in df.index:
    if df['A_D'][i] == 'D':
         if df['TROUND_ID'][i] == '        ':
             vb = df[(df['O_D'] == df['O_D'][i])
             & (df['A_D'] == 'A' )
             & (df['Terminal'] == df['Terminal'][i])
             & (df['Operator'] == df['Operator'][i])]

            number = df['number_ac'][i]
            try: ## if all the conditions above are verified a value is added to a list
                x = df.START[i] - pd.Timedelta(int(number), unit='m')
                value = vb.loc[(vb.START-x).abs().idxmin()].FlightID
            except: ## if are not verified, several strings are added to the list
                value = 'No_link_found'
        else:
            value = 'Has_link'
    else:
        value = 'IsArrival'
a.append(value)
```

My main problem is that df has millions of rows, therefore this for loop is way too time consuming. Is there any vectorized solution where I do not need to use a for loop?

Comment: This looks like it can probably be vectorized, but can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Loops in pandas should always be avoided. In above problem as well it seems you can avoid iterations by filtering at once.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is that I do not know how to adapt this code to a small example. I tried to reduce it as much as possible. Will try to edit the code a bit more.

Comment: @mad_ that isn't a universal truth.  It is a generalization that is helpful but not always true.

Comment: @piRSquared That's why I used the term "should be avoided"  and not always as you can't escape the loops every time.as eventually, they will haunt you :P

Comment: I reduced the code a bit more. However I am not able to reduce all the filtering conditions, because essentially they are the reason for my current problem.

Comment: @mad_, could you clarify what you mean by 'filtering at once'?

Comment: You could filter on the first two conditions (`df['A_D'][i] == 'D'` and `df['TROUND_ID'][i] == '        ')`) at least - hopefully this would substantially reduce the dataframe that you have to loop through? For `vb` you can also work with a dataframe that is filtered by `df['A_D'] == 'A'`.

Comment: These two lines: `number = df['number_ac'][i]` and `x = df.START[i] - pd.Timedelta(int(number), unit='m')` could also be vectorised at the start: `df['x'] = df.START - pd.Timedelta((int(df['number_ac']), unit='m')`

Comment: @Stuart, thank you very much for your comment. It helped a little bit, unfortunately it is still really time consuming. But thank you! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Use `itertuples` as the first step. Also, for the giant `df[....lots of &&]` use `df.query`, each intermediate `&&` calcualtion *iterates over the entire data-frame*. Using `df.query`, assuming you have a `numexpr`  backend, will vastly improve performance there. There may be a way to vectorize the whole thing, but those two stand out very glaringly. **never** iterate over the index, doing `df['A_D'][i]` that is *extremely* inefficient. `pandas` indexing is optimized for selecting large sections, not single rows. You incurr tons of uneccesary overhead each time you do that

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, could you explain to me how can I use df.query in this type of format? I am obtaining better performance with the solution provided by Stuart. However, it is still really time consuming

Answer (score 1):

An initial set of improvements: use `apply` rather than a loop; create a second dataframe at the start of the rows where `df["A_D"] == "A"`; and vectorise the value `x`.

```
arr = df[df["A_D"] == "A"]
# if the next line is slow, apply it only to those rows where x is needed
df["x"] = df.START - pd.Timedelta(int(df["number_ac"]), unit='m')

def link_func(row):
    if row["A_D"] != "D":
        return "IsArrival"
    if row["TROUND_ID"] != "        ":
        return "Has_link"
    vb = arr[arr["O_D"] == row["O_D"]
             & arr["Terminal"] == row["Terminal"]
             & arr["Operator"] == row["Operator"]]
    try:
        return vb.loc[(vb.START - row["x"]).abs().idxmin()].FlightID
    except:
        return "No_link_found"            

df["a"] = df.apply(link_func, axis=1)
```

Using `apply` is [apparently more efficient](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) but does not automatically vectorise the calculation. But finding a value in `arr` based on each row of `df` is inherently time consuming, however efficiently it is implemented. Consider whether the two parts of the original dataframe (where `df["A_D"] == "A"` and `df["A_D"] == "D"`, respectively) can be reshaped into a wide format somehow.

EDIT: You might be able to speed up the querying of `arr` by storing query strings in `df`, like this:

```
df["query_string"] = ('O_D == "' + df["O_D"] 
                    + '" & Terminal == "' + df["Terminal"] 
                    + '" & Operator == "' + df["Operator"] + '"')
def link_func(row):
    vb = arr.query(row["query_string"])
    try:
        row["a"] = vb.loc[(vb.START - row["x"]).abs().idxmin()].FlightID
    except:
        row["a"] = "No_link_found"

df.query('(A_D == "D") & (TROUND_ID == "        ")').apply(link_func, axis=1)
```

Comment: `.apply` is *not* more efficient than a loop using `itertuples`

Comment: Thank you for the new code @Stuart. It really helped. Do you know how can I change the code so that one value in the 'arr' dataframe changes every time the function is called? As it is, it is simple to change one cell in the df dataframe. However, I do not know how (or even if it is possible) to change a value in the 'arr' dataframe.

Comment: I think you can change values in `arr` in the usual way within the link function, but that is likely to slow it further.